# Emulator internal memory size is automatically changing to 384MB

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

```
    emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 192MB
 emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
```

I am using android studio 2.0 in windows 10 , Internal memory size automatically getting changed to 384 Mb even if I have specified 1Gb in ADB configuration..
How i can increase my emulator Internal Memory Size ?

[This is my AVD configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrbDq.jpg)

[show my emulator pic having 533 MB internal memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zB5m.jpg)

Sorry I am not able to embedded pics due to <10 reputation..

Answer (score 9):

Open AVD Manager, select your AVD. Under 'Action' column click the edit button (pencil icon). Go to Show Advanced settings and scroll down to VM heap and increase the MB to however much you need.

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

The above steps should stop the emulator warnings.

I cant see any problems with the screen shots you have provided. I can only recommend **creating a new Virtual Device** and or checking for **Android Studio Updates**. Sry I cant be of more help...

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply , I have provided two screenshot , please check those and help :)

Comment: I think the VM heap should be in divided by 64...so you should choose 320,384,448...